# SQL count max (count string) from each day

Tags: mysql, sql, count, max

I have table like this http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=miEpLUNU
Every 30mins I'm inserting wind directions. Now what I want to do is I would like to do something like this but for each day and each station.

```
SELECT DIR_GORYCZKOWA, COUNT(*) AS COUNT_DIR, DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SYSTEM, '%Y-%m-%d') AS DATE 
FROM wind_direction
WHERE DATE_SYSTEM BETWEEN '2014-02-19' AND '2014-02-20'
GROUP BY DIR_GORYCZKOWA ORDER BY COUNT_DIR DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: Remove where clause and use `GROUP BY DIR_GORYCZKOWA, DATE(DATE_SYSTEM)`

Comment: this is showing me duplicated days :-(

http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=QX2MGR5c

Comment: see my group by clause again i am using date function on `DATE_SYSTEM` and you are just using date in group by

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

```
 SELECT DIR_GORYCZKOWA, COUNT(*) AS COUNT_DIR, DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SYSTEM, '%Y-%m-%d') AS  DATE 
 FROM wind_direction
 GROUP BY DATE(DATE_SYSTEM)
 ORDER BY COUNT_DIR DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: This is only showing me one record :-(


DIR_GORYCZKOWA  COUNT_DIR  DATE
S  43  2014-03-23

Comment: This is giving me better results, but i have still duplicated days.

SELECT DIR_GORYCZKOWA, COUNT( * ) AS ILOSC, DATE_FORMAT( DATE_SYSTEM, '%Y-%m-%d' ) AS DATE
FROM wind_direction
GROUP BY DIR_GORYCZKOWA, DATE
ORDER BY DATE, ILOSC DESC

Answer (score 0):

echo_Me's answer is correct assuming that the station is stored in column "DIR_GORYCZKOWA". Keep the where clause if you want to limit the data returned to a certain date range.

The query returning these results is correct 
http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=QX2MGR5c

This is giving you the total count per station (DIR_GORYCZKOWA) per day

Comment: Ok, so how now get from this query highest count with DIR_GORYCZKOWA for each day?

I would like to have result like (for example)
SE 20 2014-04-19
E 8 2014-04-20

Comment: To get the highest count per day, you would 

ORDER BY DATE(DATE_SYSTEM), COUNT_DIR DESC

This will order the date ascending and give the highest reading first (ordered descending) per day